# CSVPrinter with break line characters

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I'm using org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter (Java 8) in order to produce a CSV text file starting from a DB RecordSet. I have a description field in my DB table on where the user can insert whatever he want, such as a new line!

As I import the CSV on Excel or Google Spreadsheet each line with a new line character in the description corrupts the CSV structure, obviously.

Should I replace/remove these characters manually or is there a way to configure CSVPrinter in order to remove it automatically?

Thank you all in advance.
F

Edit: here a code snippet:

```
    CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator("\n").withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL).withQuote('"');
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(csvContent, csvFormat);

    // prepare a list of string gathered from the DB. I explicitly use a String array because I need to perform some text editing to DB content before writing it in the CSV
    List fasciaOrariaRecord = new ArrayList();
    fasciaOrariaRecord.add(...);
    fasciaOrariaRecord.add(...);
    // ...

    csvPrinter.printRecord(csvHeader);

    // more rows...

    csvPrinter.close();
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code and explain a bit what you have tried allready?

Comment: I added a piece of code. Anyway, as you can deduce, my question was not about a specific part of code, I'd love to explore the best library usage in order to create a well formatted CSV. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any value with line endings should be escaped with quotes. If your CSV library is not doing this for you automatically I'd recommend using [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial). In your particular case, there is a [pre-built routine](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_routines.html#dumping-a-resultset) you can use to dump database contents into CSV.

Try this:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");

//Get a CSV writer settings object pre-configured for Excel
CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = Csv.writeExcel(); 
writerSettings.setHeaderWritingEnabled(true); //writes the column names to the output file

CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines(writerSettings);
//use an encoding Excel likes
routines.write(resultSet, new File("/path/to/output.csv"), "windows-1252");
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Comment: Thank you so much Jeronimo. I appreciate your answer. I do escape all the values. In addiction to your solution (the parser), are you aware of a way to perform some text editing in the cell contents before the write? I need to replace text/characters within some cells in each row. For instance: removing emoticons, replace $ with USD, ...

Comment: use writerSettings.setRowWriterProcessor and write your transformations there.